# IllegalStateException: Fragment Already Added when resuming app

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, back-stack

**Overview:**
I have a fragment-based app with a single activity. On launch, I add my main fragment and all works well. When I tap on something, I call replace() to swap out to the new fragment and add the transaction to the back stack.

**Problem:**
When the app dies in the background (or most easily repro'd with 'Don't Keep Activities'), and I relaunch the app from the home screen, I get the exception below.

**Scenario:**
1. Open app
2. Navigate to a secondary fragment (this problem doesn't occur if you never leave the main fragment)
3. Background the app
4. Let the app die naturally (~24hr), or enable 'Don't Keep Activites' in the Developer Options
5. Open app from home screen

**Expected:**
App opens to main fragment (regardless of what fragment was displayed when backgrounded)

**Actual:**
Crash below

**Other Requirements:**
- Background app and immediately tap from home screen must return to previous fragment (assuming it wasn't destroyed in the background).

**Stack Trace (note absolutely no calls from my app itself, so nowhere for me to debug):**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rcg.socialstitch/com.rcg.socialstitch.ViewStitchActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: ViewStitchFragment{42800520 #1 id=0x7f040030}
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2276)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: ViewStitchFragment{42800520 #1 id=0x7f040030}
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1133)
       at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:618)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5320)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2190)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2276)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: `note absolutely no calls from my app itself, so nowhere for me to debug` sure there is, look here `Fragment already added: ViewStitchFragment{42800520 #1 id=0x7f040030}` so check and see if the fragment exists before you add it

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. My code to add the fragment never is run in this case. It is unwinding something from the back stack.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have solved this. My .replace() calls all added to the back stack, but my initial .add() did not. When I ensured my initial fragment addition was no the back stack, this no longer seems to happen.